# C# Repository CSV Question. What does this code do exactly?

Tags: c#

What does this code mean? Somehow it generates a .csv file on my side but I cannot seem to find it. I am using it as a data source.

```
public CSVRepository()
{
    var filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFileName"];
    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename;
}
```

Comment: That code does not look complete. It retrieves a file name from the application configuration and builds a path (that may be used as a destination for a .csv file), but it does not actually write the file to disk. Could you please include some context about where you found this code? How you're using it?

Comment: This looks like a constructor of a class. This class has methods for sure and these methods do what you see.

Comment: The code you posted does not, _'... generates a .csv file...'_, it set's a `path` property that is most likely used by the un-posted code that actually writes the file.

Answer (score 2):

The code runs as the constructor of a class. It looks in an `app.config` xml file to find a `CSVFileName` xml element. It uses the value of the element as a filename (no path, just the name). Then it looks up the path where the program is running, appends the filename to that path, and sets the result to a member field in the class that will be used by other code in the class to write out your csv file.

Comment: Your post exactly answers the OP's question. +1

Comment: Thanks! I just looked in app.config and found what I need.